# Reset Windows 8.1 password Linuxmint on a dualboot config?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, linux-mint, password-recovery

My laptop is in a dualboot config with linuxmint can I reset forgotten windows password from mint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Offline NT Password & Registry Editor (chntpw) [bootdisk](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html), or since you have Linux installed already simply use the [static linked binaries](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/editor.html) instead. Be sure to read the documentation and [walkthrough](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/walkthrough.html) first.